# JS insertBefore() and pass a string contains html

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way how I can insert things before an element in plain javascript.

I have a footer element:

```
//html
<footer>
  ...
</footer>

// js
var footer = document.querySelector('footer')
```

and I want to add this string containing html before it:

```
var string = "<div class='sun'><p>hi and more things</p>...</div>"
```

In jQuery I'd simply do this:

```
$(footer).before(string)
```

But how I can do it in plain javascript? How to convert the string to NODE and then display?

Comment: insertBefore() is the function you could use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', string)`

```js
var string = "<div class='sun'><p>hi and more things</p>...</div>"

document.querySelector('footer').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', string);
```

```html
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
fragment.innerHTML = "<div class='sun'><p>hi and more things</p>...</div>";
var footer = document.querySelector('footer');
document.body.insertBefore(fragment, footer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this .Better do with `createElement()` instead of `string element creation` in dom

**[`parentNode.insertBefore(newnode, existingnode)`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp)**

```js
var footer = document.querySelector('footer')

var string = document.createElement('div')
string.class='sun'
string.innerHTML ='<p>hi and more things</p>'

document.body.insertBefore(string,footer)
```

```html
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks, just curious: Why is it better than using insertAdjacentHTML?

Comment: i was mention with  element creation not with `insert` function